# Extending another TypeScript function with additional arguments

Tags: typescript, overloading

Is it possible in [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) to define a function type and extend its argument list in another type (overloading function type?)?

Let's say I have this type:

```
type BaseFunc = (a: string) => Promise<string>
```

I want to define another type with one additional argument `(b: number)` and the same return value.

If at some point in the future `BaseFunc` adds or changes arguments this should also be reflected in my overloaded function type.

Comment: At the beginning of the parameter list or at the end ? At the start is the simple option.

Comment: @Titian Either would be fine though I'd prefer the start.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) together with [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) and the [inference behavior of conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496) to extract the parameters from the signature and reconstruct the new signature.

```
type BaseFunc = (a: string) => Promise<string>

type BaseWithB  = BaseFunc extends (...a: infer U) => infer R ? (b: number, ...a:U) => R: never;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out though as I wrote above I'll go with the "options" solution since it seems cleaner and more flexible.

Comment: @Thomas sure no problem, I agree that is a better design. I was just answering the specific typescript question you asked :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thanks a lot for your answer. That is exactly what I need, because I need type definitions for already existing 3rd party library. Therefore changing function signature is not possible.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thanks. What if I want that `b` will be the last param? (It gives `A rest parameter must be last in a parameter list.ts(1014)`)

Comment: @MoshFeu in ts 4.0+ you can do `type BaseWithB  = BaseFunc extends (...a: infer U) => infer R ? (...a:[...U, number]) => R: never;`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir But this removes the parameters names, due to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39941

Comment: @splintor are you sure that doesn't apply only to tuple spread ? It seems to preserve parameters names https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgMQK4DsDGUC8UAUcRcAXFAsAE4CW6A5gJS4B8UACpQPYC21SAPBRr1mAKFGhIsRBADq1YAAsYUXNKRosUCAA9gEdABMEBAHTnSUWgDMIlKAFUmOVjbtQASlAD8BAEZk6KjcfnYANFDmpqROLJ6BEABudgDc4gA2EMBQOmTwSPJKMGlAA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Not if the new parameter is added to the tuple at the end: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgMQK4DsDGUC8UAUcRcAXFAsAE4CW6A5gJS4B8UACpQPYC21SAPBRr1mAKFGhIsRBADq1YAAsYUXNKRosUCAA9gEdABMEBAHTnSUWgDMIlKAFUmOVjbtQASlAD8ZiyQBtc1MHABooACMydFRuCLsAXWdWD2iIADc7AG5xABsIYCgdMngkeSUYHKA (I was referring to your answer to MoshFeu)

Comment: I found out that now `Parameters<>` returns `Labeled Tuple Elements` so you can use  that to extend https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgMQK4DsDGUC8UAUARgFxQLABOAlugOYCUuAfFAAoUD2AtlUgDzlqdJgChQkWIggB1KsAAWMKLklI0WKBAAewCOgAmCAgDpTcUjQBmEClACqjHCys2oAJSgB+E2eIBtU2M7ABoodFQuQhsAXUcWN1J0CAA3GwBuEREAeiyoAHc5eTC4LggEMXBoeCRZBRgAJmU8apQMbG1dAyN8QPMoOHQQP1jmKBdbD28e3wDTO1JWOAoSiF0KBD4W9UwmUKXaAGZEiKiKEad3RJT0oA

Answer (score 11):

**UPD:** it's possible to *extend* a function's parameters in TypeScript. See Titian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52294058/1201488).

Original answer: I doubt that it can be done in the way you described. However, you can try something like this:

```
interface BaseOptions {
    a: string;
}
type BaseFunc = (options: BaseOptions) => Promise<string>

interface DerivedOptions implements BaseOptions {
    b: number;
} 
type DerivedFunc = (options: DerivedOptions) => Promise<string>
```

Another advantage of this approach is that you have *named parameters* for free. So it's going to be cleaner from a caller side than just calling `BaseFunc` or `DerivedFunc` with positional arguments. Just compare:

```
someFuncA(1, undefined, true);

// vs

someFuncB({nofiles: 1, enableLogging: true});  // and bar: undefined is just omitted
```

Comment: Never doubt Typescript ;). But your solution is arguably cleaner then what is requested.

Comment: Thanks guys! I also think this solution is preferable. It also allows me to construct the options object in other scenarios. Something I would be blocked from doing with the type directly. Marking this as best answer.

Answer (score 10):

You could use spread with Parameters<>:

```
function base(a: number, b: number, c: number): number
function derived(add: string, ...base: Parameters<typeof base>): number
```

The restriction is that base parameters have to be on the end.

Comment: great solution! :thumbsup:

Comment: And the return type can also be replaced with `ReturnType<base>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make any additional arguments optional.

```js
class Plant {
  grow(inches: number) {}
}

class Grass extends Plant {
  // adding new optional argument in override
  grow(inches:number, cutOff?: boolean) {}
}

class CrabGrass extends Grass {
  // At this level of overriding, you no longer need it to be optional
  grow(inches:number, cutOff: boolean) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, for those that ended up on this page just looking to quickly add another definition to your function interface:

**Intersection type in Typescript**

> A & in TS in the context of a types means an intersection type. It
> merges all properties of 2 object types together and creates a new
> type

Example:

```
const SomeComponent: React.FC<Omit<ISomeInterface, 'arg1' | 'arg2' | 'arg3'>
 & { oneMoreArgument: string; }> = ({ arg1, arg2, arg3, oneMoreArgument }) => {

... function stuff

}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the same problem as the one stated in the question. React.FC<T> extends the prop interface which is not equivalent to extending the raw arguments list of a function. You can easily extend the prop interface separately and then simply use that as the generic. I'd argue it's easier to read as well. In the example you are simply manipulating an interface (omit + add) and then using it as the type of a single argument not actually modifying the top-level arguments.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to show how to modify the type of a single argument. So, if you have a function that has a pre-defined interface for it's arguments, but, you want to modify it to have one more definition for a particular use case, instead of creating a new function interface. The `React.FC` was just an example.

Comment: @Thomas It would be awesome to get an example on how to simplify this as you describe.

Comment: no problem :) I usually don't use `React.FC` anymore as it adds things like `children` which I may not need. Functional components in react are basically any function that returns something react can render which means there is no need to decorate it any further than that. Something like this: https://gist.github.com/rudfoss/30615a4e8b99dece4a387b9b2b854973 is very close to what I usually use.

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of the powerful [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) utility types, **so we don't even have to parametrize the initial function parameters ourselves,** as this can be particularly problematic and time-consuming in more complex types.

I'll showcase a real-life scenario where I recently had to make use of this pattern.
Consider the following function, which was opened by a click of `<button>`

```
openPopup = (event, isNotif) => { /*...*/ }
```

- Now issue is, we can't manually type `event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>` because the interface `MouseEvent` does not accept any generics, producing a [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) error.
- We can however type our function as `MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>`
- This however still does not solve our issue, as  `MouseEventHandler` does not expect a custom second argument, yet another [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) error.

We can however create a derived function handler in the following way:

```
type PopupHandler = (
  event: Parameters<MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>>[0]
  isNotif: boolean
) => ReturnType<MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElemement>>

// now it works!
openPopup: PopupHandler = (event, isNotif) => { /*...*/ }
```

- We use `Parameters` utility type, to infer the event type as the first argument out of the args array
- We use `ReturnType` to keep the proper type of return type.

This way we can actually extend *(overload)* an existing function type with our custom parameter while retaining the return type and maintaining proper types all throughout.